# hidden input value is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get the value of my hidden field `lengthIndicator` :

```
<div class="dwr_frame_wpr">
        <div class="dwr_arrow_left L"></div>
        <div class="dwr_frame L">
            <div class="dwr_biggy">
                <div class="dwr_box L"></div>
                <div class="dwr_box L"></div>
                <div class="dwr_box L"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="points_wpr">

            </div>
            <input type="hidden" class="lengthIndicator" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" class="whatNowIndicator" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="dwr_arrow_right L"></div>
    </div>
```

Now, I have a JS code that basically count the length of `lengthIndicator`, and write it in the hidden input type. (thats happening on "`ready`").

after that, on "`click`" , Im tryint to read the input , and its showing undefind on the console. Im trying to unserstand why ?

(this is the code : (im passing a "dwr_arrow_left" element on click.)  )

```
checkHowManySliders: function (el) {
        console.log(el);
        var lengthInd = el.find('.lengthIndicator');
        console.log(el.find('.lengthIndicator').val());

    }
```

when Im console the element , it says its getting the element great, but when Im trying to watch the value its getting undefined.

Comment: `lengthIndicator` is not a child of the `dwr_arrow_left`, because `dwr_arrow_left` is empty div. Try to pass `dwr_frame_wpr` element

Comment: oops , you are correct :P

Comment: sometimes all you need is another pair of eyes..   place your answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lengthIndicator` is not a child of the `dwr_arrow_left`, because `dwr_arrow_left` is empty div. Try to pass `dwr_frame` element.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fL39bbr7/)

Answer (score 1):

max-brodin is correct. This should fix your problem.

```
 var lengthInd = el.parent().find('.lengthIndicator');
 console.log(el.parent().find('.lengthIndicator').val());
```